# How to sign Multiple Flavor APK's with a Single Keystore

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have 11 flavors for an app and one Keystore for an app. I hoped to use one keystore to sign multiple product flavors like below.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("Users/avalon/retailr.jks")
        storePassword storePassword
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword keyPassword
    }
}
...
...
productFlavors{
    flavorone {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    flavortwo {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }



}
```

However i keep getting an error during running a Configuration that  `The apk for your currently selected variant cannot be signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant (flavorone-release)`. Does that mean I have to make 11 different keystore configurations for the apps or is there a way i can use one ?

Comment: Sounds more like a bug. Do you have enabled parallel execution of gradle? If yes this could be a concurrency problem (all flavors run signing at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this ?

```
  signingConfigs {
    configFlavor1 {
        keyAlias 'abcdef'
        keyPassword 'password'
        storeFile file('keystore.jks')
        storePassword 'password'
    }

    configFlavor2 {
        keyAlias 'abcdef'
        keyPassword 'password'
        storeFile file('keystore.jks')
        storePassword 'password'
    }

}
```

Then in

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        productFlavors.flavor1.signingConfig signingConfigs.configFlavor1
       

        productFlavors.flavor2.signingConfig signingConfigs.configFlavor2
    }
```

Comment: That actually works thanks. Are there any problems/violations arising from signing the app with the same key once you upload the apps to Playstore ?

Comment: Where is the part that "connects" here between the package-name and the key-configuration to sign with ("configFlavor1", "configFlavor2") ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add multiple configs for each variant. In the app/build.gradle you can mention in the build types like following

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

and in your signinconfig section you can have like following

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'keyAlias'
            keyPassword 'keyPassword'
            storePassword 'storePassword'
            storeFile file("${rootDir}/keystores/app.keystore")
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have done this. Release has a signing config. But still get the error above.